# Lipschitz gradient of product with softmax function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis, machine-learning, lipschitz-functions

Let $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be $C^1$ for $i=1,...,n$.  Under what (reasonable) conditions on the $f_i$ does the function
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \operatorname{softmax}(f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x))_if_i(x),
$$
have Lipschitz gradients?

Where the $\operatorname{softmax}(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^N e^{z_i}}$.  I tried using the constants of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020867/machine-learning-is-the-softmax-function-lipschitz-with-lipschitz-constant-1) but to no avail...